# Library project VS reference library in Eclipse (Android)

Tags: android, eclipse, jar

In Eclipse (Android development) you can go to project properties and then:

1. Open "Android" and in "Library" section press "Add" button to add library project.
2. Open "Java build path" and add JAR file of the same project.

In first case, you can see the JAR file under "Library projects" section; in second case - the same jar under "Referenced libraries".

What the difference of these 2 approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a project is an Android library project and includes Android resources, those resources will be made available to the application that includes it as a library project.

If the jar is included as a referenced jar, you don't have access to the resources.